# Как из словаря получить значение заданного ключа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Каким образом можно получить отсюда `amount`?

```
{'accounts': [{'alias': 'qw_wallet_rub', 'fsAlias': 'qb_wallet', 
               'bankAlias': 'QIWI', 'title': 'Qiwi Account', 
               'type': {'id': 'WALLET', 'title': 'Visa QIWI Wallet'},
               'hasBalance': True, 'balance': {'amount': 16.71, 'currency': 643},
               'currency': 643, 'defaultAccount': True}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'accounts': [{'alias': 'qw_wallet_rub', 'fsAlias': 'qb_wallet', 'bankAlias': 'QIWI', 'title': 'Qiwi Account', 'type': {'id': 'WALLET', 'title': 'Visa QIWI Wallet'}, 'hasBalance': True, 'balance': {'amount': 16.71, 'currency': 643}, 'currency': 643, 'defaultAccount': True}]}

>>> my_dict['accounts'][0]['balance']['amount']
16.71
```

---

Все ключи словаря:

```
>>> my_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['accounts'])
```

Тип и размер:

```
>>> type(my_dict['accounts'])
<class 'list'>
>>> len(my_dict['accounts'])
1
```

И так далее:

```
>>> my_dict['accounts'][0].keys()
dict_keys(['alias', 'fsAlias', 'bankAlias', 'title', 'type', 'hasBalance', 'balance', 'currency', 'defaultAccount'])

>>> my_dict['accounts'][0]['balance']
{'amount': 16.71, 'currency': 643}
```

Comment: да помогло, я щас тоже решил этот вопрос, когда проверил через type() значение

Answer (score 4):

Можно также воспользоваться удобным [модулем dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), который позволяет "общаться" со словарями используя пути как в `xpath`:

```
import dpath.util as dpu  #  pip install dpath

In [18]: dpu.values(data, "/accounts/**/amount")
Out[18]: [16.71]

In [19]: dpu.search(data, "/accounts/**/amount")
Out[19]: {'accounts': [{'balance': {'amount': 16.71}}]}
```